PolarDB GDN: will a new Endpoint be used after a secondary cluster is promoted a primary cluster?
We are trying out the GDN (Global Database Network) provided by Alibaba PolarDB. I have a question on cluster switching. After switching a secondary cluster to a primary cluster, will the new primary cluster get a new EndPoint? If so, it means that the user application needs to get updated with the new EndPoint's link address?
Still under research

Yes, after switching a secondary cluster to a primary cluster, the new primary cluster will get a new EndPoint, and the user application needs to get updated with the new EndPoint's link address。
